# What is the difference between wavelength and period?

Tags: basic

Currently I have some problems with basic terms and need some help please. 
 
I'd like to know:

[image: wavelength and period]

1. What difference exists between wavelength and period ? 
    When should I use the name wavelength and when period ?

Comment: Single design questions are required

Comment: How would you make a VCO if there was only quartz!

Comment: http://webaudio.prototyping.bbc.co.uk/wobbulator/ you need one if you are making early sci-fi music

Comment: " For me, wavelength and period is the same." Only if you think that 1 metre (distance) = 1 second (time). Just because the graphs have the same shape doesn't make them the same. You need to look at the axis quantities. The frequency and period of a wave are related by the formula velocity of wave (metres per second) = frequency (measured in Hertz) x Wavelength (in metres). The period is the **reciprocal**  (T = 1/f) of the frequency and 1 Hertz = 1 cycle per second)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it is too broad (although it is poorly stated). As a proof take the comment of @JImDearden. With some care that comment can become a good answer perfectly fitting this format. If I could, I'd vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is reflected in the horizontal axis in each plot: wavelength is a displacement in space, and period is a displacement in time. You would use wavelength when you are talking about spatial relations, e.g. the length of an antenna, and you would use period when you are talking about temporal relations, e.g. circuit trigger occurrences.